# SSIS Update multiple table values from update tables

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a process that is pulling between 150k-200k rows of data daily from a flat file into mssql server. Once the data is in the server, I am performing some cleanup on the data. One thing that is needed is to update some of the data based on update tables. These tables will contain updates for particular customers, for example:

```
Customer  Current_Location     Update_Location
ABC       New York, New York   New York, NY
ABC       Brooklyn, New York   New York, NY
BDE       New York, New York   New York
```

Only around 10% of the records would need to be updated. In the case above the rest of the customers would keep the Current_Location value. I have six of these tables that need to update the primary dataset. The two solutions that I have come up are:

1. Use multiple Lookup transformations (would require 6 dataflow tasks)
2. Use an execute sql task with a simple update statement

What would be the most efficient/proper option?

Comment: I would think the Update Statement would be the most efficient. SSIS is great for moving things around, but if you want to do a lot of "special" things, I always like the SQL statement, plus if you do it as a SPROC its much easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, i'll look up more on stored procedures.